# Problem using Nginx and Apache both for Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, nginx, server-setup, apache2

I am trying to use nginx as static web server front and apache processing the back end for Magento. but magento is showing me this error: ***Your web server is set up incorrectly and allows unauthorized access to sensitive files. Please contact your hosting provider.***

**Here is my website.conf for Nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

#   root /var/www/website.com/html;
#   index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name website.com www.website.com;

        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/website.com/html;
        set $MAGE_MODE developer;

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

    index index.php;
    autoindex off;
    charset off;

    location /setup {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;
        location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
            fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    location /update {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;

        location ~ ^/update/index.php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny everything but index.php
        location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /pub {
        location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
            deny all;
        }
        alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

 location /static/ {
    if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
      expires max;
    }

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version {
      rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
      add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
      expires +1y;

      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
      }
    }

    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
      add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
      expires off;

      if (!-f $request_filename) {
         rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
      }
    }

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  }

    location /media/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;

        location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires    off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }

    location /media/customer/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/downloadable/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location /media/import/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ cron\.php {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503|phpinfo)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=1024M \n max_execution_time=18000";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

       location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

                location ~ \.php$ {      
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
         }

}

upstream fastcgi_backend {
    # socket
    # server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    # use tcp connection
    #  server  127.0.0.1:9000;

}
```

**Here is my website.conf for apache**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/website.com/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost> 
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Now I am trying to open phpinfo.php so I create new php file in the `pub` folder. Now whenever I tried to open website.com/phpinfo.php in browser it starts to download it.

What wrong I'm doing here?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first your nginx is not configured as frontend cache/proxy server.
you have 2 `\.php$` blocks, one for php-fpm upstream and one for apache backend.

then probably apache is not configured to process php.

your best option is to use nginx as proxy cache + php-fpm servers loop. 
remove apache.

Comment: I think you are right. Do you know any tutorials, where I can learn how to use both of them together?

Comment: you can use google

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, what you're trying to do is extremely complex and unlikely to work, unless you are a high-level expert at both Apache and Nginx.

What it sounds like you are doing is kind of like having a humidifyer and a dehumidifyer in the same room, fighting it out.

I won't put out a strong opinion on why you should be using Apache vs. Nginx.  I've used both, and worked on sites with one or the other.  I find working with .htaccess files a little easier (i.e. Apache) to handle redirects, but NginX also has advantages at times.

I don't think it's ideal to use both at the same time on the same server.  I'm sure it is technically possible, but it's pretty confusing and prone to having significant issues.

If you really, really need to do this, I might recommend having one front end web server running apache; have a backend database that handles the mySQL database, and then a third server that is an admin server, and you could use NginX for that.

I hope this helps...